# Travis CI Secret Key Issue

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to integrate Travis CI for my Android project. I have 4 secret keys and URLs. However, I am getting below error:

> Could not get unknown property 'BASE_URL' for DefaultConfig_Decorated...

**My secrets:**

```
buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", BASE_URL
buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_ID", ACCOUNT_ID
buildConfigField "String", "API_TOKEN", API_TOKEN
buildConfigField "String", "GOOGLE_PLACES_BASE_URL", GOOGLE_PLACES_BASE_URL
```

In addition, I added these keys to the Settings page on Travis.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wATG1.jpg

**A part of .travis.yml**

```
env:
  global:
    - ACCOUNT_ID=ACCOUNT_ID
    - API_TOKEN=API_TOKEN
    - BASE_URL=BASE_URL
    - GOOGLE_PLACES_BASE_URL=GOOGLE_PLACES_BASE_URL
```

How can I make Travis detect these keys properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone interested?

Comment: You ever figure this out? Having same problem

Comment: Hi @Kyle I switched to CircleCi, it is simpler than Travis, and documentation is very helpful.